# Mouse-less use of Windows 7 -- Selection of windows?

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, mouseless

So I have been slowly transitioning to using my keyboard for faster use of my computer but have been looking for an alternative to alt+tab and win+tab for selecting windows. I am hoping someone knows of a program that would let me select windows similar to several windows managers on linux where the windows are numbered in the corners and then activated through a command or hotkey combo.

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but if you really wanna go mouseless in Windows, I highly recommend LabelControl - an AHK utility that lets you 'click' on various controls without the mouse: http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Skrommel/index.html#LabelControl

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm on Linux now so I can't test all shortcuts, but:

- If you have more monitors, then <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> / <kbd>→</kbd> moves window through monitors.
- <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>...<kbd>0</kbd> runs the program at the selected position on the taskbar
- <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> / <kbd>→</kbd> / <kbd>↑</kbd> / <kbd>↓</kbd> tiles windows across the screen
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> will spawn a new process
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + click will run a program in elevated mode

What you are essentially looking for is an old program called [Switcher](http://insentient.net/Files/Projects/Switcher/Switcher-2.0.0.2705.msi).

If you are more experienced and looking to create shortcuts that can switch among (send windows to) different virtual workspaces and/or setting windows "always on top" and other things, I'd recommend [VirtuaWin](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/virtuawin/VirtuaWin_unicode_setup_4.3.exe). You don't have to use virtual desktops to have the ability to set some global shortcuts for other things.

Comment: Switcher was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you! After a little bit of tweaking I got it to match the rest of my theme and have it set to display all the windows with Ctrl + Alt + Numpad 0 and then pressing the window number selects the window.

Answer (score 3):

You can use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Any Number</kbd> to select Application windows based on taskbar ordering. Pressing the number key multiple times while holding down the <kbd>Win</kbd> key will cycle through windows for that application. If the application has no windows open, then this shortcut will launch the application.